# UWP connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, database, uwp

I want to create a connection for my UWP and database. I want the uwp to send a value to the database.

```
 MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
            string myConnectionString;

            myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1; uid = root;" + "pwd=root;database=test";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
            }

            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {

            }
```

Is this the correct way to write the connection ? and where do I write this part of the coding at ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kntdp.png)

Main page or any of my other page ? (scenario 1-3)

Comment: How do I test it ?

Comment: I would suggest running it. if `conn.Open` doesn't throw an exception, you are likely fine.

Comment: it has an exception though. How do I fix it ?

Comment: I have added "SslMode=None" but still has exception tho

Comment: nvm I fixed it already haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your content looks right, I would try to use 'localhost' rather than ip.

```
var myConnection = new MySqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = "database=test;server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root";
myConnection.Open();
```

More info see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ConnectionString.htm

I would also check here to see if you are providing enough info, which you are. https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

In terms of connecting to the database, it depends. What type of application is this? Typically, database connections are made during the start of the application. If you are using Entity Framework, you'll want your Database Context to manage the connection (which is an entirely different topic).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Are you free to add me on skype ? because I need help in this database thingy